# Delphi TProc<Integer> - can parameter value be changed

Tags: delphi

Can `TProc<T>` be made to allow aValue not just to be read, but to be edited in a `TProc` anonymous procedure?

```
var xProc2: TProc<Integer>;
xProc2 := procedure(aValue: Integer)
  begin
    aValue := 5;
  end;
```

Delphi 10.4.x

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If code requires exactly `TProc<Integer>;`, then no. You can change local copy of value-type argument and use it inside procedure, but external code doesn't see changes.

If possible, you can use pointer argument of type `PInteger`, and change `aValue^`.

Also you can define own generic type with `var` parameter

```
type
   TProcvar<T> = reference to procedure (var Arg1: T);
```

and apply it

```
var xProc2: TProcVar<Integer>;
xProc2 := procedure(var aValue: Integer)
  begin
    aValue := 5;
  end;
```

But the most reliable way, I think - use **function**  `TFunc<T,TResult>`  ( or `TFunc<TResult>` if you don't use input argument)

```
var xFunc: TFunc<Integer, Integer>;
xfunc := function(aValue: Integer): Integer
  begin
    Result := aValue + 5;
  end;
```

Comment: thanks so much! I didn't realise there was a TFunc!